# go-gin unable to set cookies

Tags: cookies, go, go-gin

I am trying to set a cookie on an HTML page

```
 func testCookie(c *gin.Context) {
    c.SetCookie("test1", "testvalue", 10, "/", "", true, true)
    c.HTML(200, "dashboard", gin.H{
        "title":    "Dashboard",
        }
    }
```

This should have set the cookie on the HTML page but it doesn't.
My server is running to serve https requests. I am not sure why I am not able to set cookies here.

Comment: Cookies are set in the response, and you're looking at the cookies present in the request.

Comment: Please don't edit your question completely once you have received answers on it.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to comments above 
Try using

```
c.SetCookie("cookieName", "name", 10, "/", "yourDomain", true, true)
```

example

```
c.SetCookie("gin_cookie", "someName", 60*60*24, "/", "google.com", true, true)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`SetCookie()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#SetCookie) sets the cookie on the `ResponseWriter`'s headers hence you can read its value in subsequent requests where it can be read using [`Request`](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request) object's `Cookie()` method.

Here's the [related code](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/master/context.go#L360) of the same to give you an idea:

```
func (c *Context) SetCookie(
    name string,
    value string,
    maxAge int,
    path string,
    domain string,
    secure bool,
    httpOnly bool,
) {
    if path == "" {
        path = "/"
    }
    http.SetCookie(c.Writer, &http.Cookie{
        Name:     name,
        Value:    url.QueryEscape(value),
        MaxAge:   maxAge,
        Path:     path,
        Domain:   domain,
        Secure:   secure,
        HttpOnly: httpOnly,
    })
}

func (c *Context) Cookie(name string) (string, error) {
    cookie, err := c.Request.Cookie(name)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    val, _ := url.QueryUnescape(cookie.Value)
    return val, nil
}
```

---

## **Update**

You won't be able to access cookies in your page because you're passing [`HttpOnly` as `true`](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly). When this is set to true only the server has access to the cookies and you can't fetch their values in front-end using Javascript.

Comment: `c.SetCookie("test1", "testvalue", 10, "/", "", true, true)
 c.HTML(200, "dashboard", gin.H{
  "title":    "Dashboard",
}` This should have ideally set the cookie on the HTML page but its not working

Comment: @love2code What do you mean by it should set in HTML page? A cookie is part of the headers. Considering you're passing HttpOnly as True you won't be able to access the cookie using Javascript either.

Comment: @love2code Read more about HttpOnly cookie here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly